# Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set Spring Boot SqlServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can not connect Spring boot with SQL Server

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.134.92;databaseName=Attendance_Device
spring.datasource.username=emon
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2018Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = false
```

Comment: Remove spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2018Dialect and spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: @SimonMartinelli 
NOW THIS ERROR OCCURS
The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.134.92, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Comment: That means that you cannot connect to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend check 3 things

1. Gradle or pom.xml dependency setting check.

   - Make sure dependencies of SQL set what you using
2. DB server firewall check

   - Check your server or router. Firewall could be block networking
3. DB server address or id/pw check

   - Check your DB infos